# Securely store a db password without setting up a service

Tags: javascript, python, windows, security, iis

Currently making an web application for our users to access and edit a database

We only have one connection to this database and can't make more, but we also can't give this one credential to any of our web app future users.

The idea is to create another security layer in the application using windows accounts

Pseudo code :

```
db = "dbconnection1"
dbuser = "admin1"
dbpassword = "123456"

enabledWinUsers = { "winUsr1", "winUsr2", "winUsr3" }

winusr = aplication.getWinUser()

if winusr in enabledWinUsers :
    db.connect( db, dbuser, dbpassword )
```

The database logic and connection will all be done in Python, for now, and the app in Javascript/Jquery

Question is, is it possible to secure this code or the db credentials in any way without setting up a service like Node.js?

I do have full access to the server machine running the web app

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't had my coffee yet.  You are saying that you want your JS code on the client side to talk to the DB on the server directly? I hope not.  What is the backend code?  c#?  vb?

Comment: @Zuzlx its python, javascript is just the front end that will call the py script

Comment: Maybe add py tag to the question so you get the py gang attention

Comment: If you allow a program to automatically impersonate a real (domain) user, you have a security issue. Accountability is gone. You need to look for a more appropriate solution.

Comment: @IInspectable basically the application will connect as "editor" user, and the db doesn't care who is the editor as there is no editor tracking in it

Comment: In that case, the [Data Protection API (DPAPI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) would be the right choice. I don't know, how to access it from Python/JavaScript, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can encrypt the user credentials in your source code and decrypt them from your source code. Another option is to set the credentials as environment variables